# how to set empty rows on bottom whenever sort gird extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am creating a sample i want to show blank rows after fill data on grid.
Here is my code for add empty rows on grid

```
  var records = [];
        for (var row = 15; row > 0; row--) {
            records.push({});
        }
        this.lookupReference('mygrid').getStore().add(records);
```

after fill data my output grid is-:

[image: output screenshot]

Now i am sorting by group id just click on Id header. Now blank row shows on top.

Output screenshot

[image: error outout]

Please suggest me to set blank rows on bottom on all case

Comment: Btw why do you put the empty rows there?

Comment: user can type on empty grid for add record

Comment: I see, the best way for you would be to overwrite the sort function on the column class you use. You would have to take a better look into the source code of the framework as these functions are not exposed normally.

Comment: thanks  pagep for reply me. How i will do it can you tell me example. I am new in extjs since 1 month. If possible can give me hint on short with code.

Comment: Which exact version of ExtJS are you using - it looks old? From 6.0.1 there is sorter config of column exposed where you can write your own sort function http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html if you are on 4.1.3 there is sorter config on the Store http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.Sortable-cfg-sorters unfortunately I don't have much experience / time to look into this, maybe you find the answer somewhere, try to google "extjs custom sorter" something like that...